# GF65 Thin (RTX3060, 10750H) crahes after installing 3200MHz RAM

Tags: memory, crash

I decided to add some RAM to my GF65 Thin and got a 64Gb Kingston Fury kit with 3200Mhz RAM.

Initially all booted up fine but then the laptop shut itself off after a few minutes. I rebooted and tried again but it crashed a few minutes later just like before. And then it kept happening several times.

Re-installed the original Samsung 2666MHz 16Gb kit and all is working fine again.

Obviously, not giving an awful lot of information but I simply can't run any memory tests because laptop shuts down within 1-2 minutes of being turned on.

It shouldn't be the fact that the RAM in 3200 MHz? Even if MB doesn't support it fully, it should still work at a lower clock, right?

Not quite sure what to do and how to check what could be the issue. The only clue is that when I opened it up to put original RAM back in, the case was kinda warm, more so than the usual. But I don't know how new RAM may affect the thermal performance.

Comment: Are you 100% your system supports 16 GB modules?

Comment: This could be a power issue. Are you sure that the new modules don't draw more power than the original ones? Because if they do, it might exceed the maximum allowed power draw of one of your components, thus shutting the PC down.

Comment: @Ramhound, the new RAM comes in 2x32Gb modules. I checked and the maximum supported RAM by the MB is 64 Gb and given there's only 2 RAM slots, it should support 32 Gb modules.

Comment: @DLCom, I'll have to investigate this, thanks. I'm be surprised if new RAM didn't draw more power than the old one, but I doubt that some small fraction or a couple of Watts of difference would be enough to crash the system. The combined CPU and GPU at the max would draw 160 Watts while power supply is 180 Watts (and the screen was off since I'm using external monitor)

Comment: @pavel The thing is that not only the psu has a maximum power rating, but also the individual components, especially in a Laptop that isn't "supposed" to be upgraded and thus constructed with relatively slim safety margins. So it might very well be that not the rating of the PSU, but that of the individual RAM slots is exceeded.

Comment: Power isnt a problem, they use 1.2V which is the standard for your laptop. RAM speed is limited to 2666Mhz and the laptop has no support for XMP. I couldnt find any information on Kingston Fury RAM and your laptop, but crucial claims to have compatible memory here https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/msi-(micro-star)/gf65-thin-9sd#memory Maybe you're best off returning this ram and getting some Crucial instead ?

Comment: And one more thing you could do is check if your BIOS allows you to set DRAM speed by hand, so you can fix it to 2666Mhz instead of "Auto". It should do this automaticly anyway, especially since the mainboard doesnt support speeds over 2666Mhz, but its worth a shot i guess.

Comment: @pavel - Some of the early Intel hardware that supported 32 GB modules, only supported lower frequency modules, what generation does the GF65 Thin support? I don't trust the accuracy of Google results when it comes to OEM equipment.  It is suspect the laptop failed to POST with higher frequency memory, that indicates, it doesn't support the higher frequency.  It also wouldn't necessary underclock the modules out of the box.  Where did you see that it support 64 GB exactly?